# How to use window.open only when the window is not opened?

Tags: javascript

How can I use JavaScript:

```
window.open('url','_blank');
```

only when the window is not opened?

And if it is already opened, I need to focus it.

Answer (score 0):

You can store a reference to the window and check its `closed` property like this:

```
var openedWindow;

function openWindow() {
  if (!openedWindow || openedWindow.closed) {
    openedWindow = window.open('url','_blank');
  }
}
```

Comment: the moment i do the                                                                               var openedWindow = window.open('url','_blank'); it opens a new tab

Comment: So, just wrap it to the conditional statement:
var openedWindow;
if (!openedWindow || openedWindow.closed) {
openedWindow = window.open('url','_blank');
}

Comment: See the updated response.